# Auto resolve conflicts in smartgit while rebasing

Tags: git, conflict, rebase, smartgit

There is this nice feature in smartgit that sets the conflicted file as the rebase target, which is
by invoking the command '**Set to rebase target ("theirs")**' on the file.

However, I want this to be done **automatically** on every conflicted file during rebasing. There are just so many commits and conflicted files that resolving each file manually is very time consuming.

Is there a way to make **smartgit** perform that resolution automatically ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If smartgit is as smart as git then just go a head with

```
git rebase -s recursive -X theirs
```

Comment: thanks, what command should I add if I were to rebase on 'upstream' ?
something like ``git rebase upstream -s recursive -X theirs`` ?

Comment: `git rebase -s revursive -X theirs upstream`

Comment: I have `my_branch` that is set to track `origin/dev`. The status is that `Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged,
and have 41 and 200 different commits each`. I executed the command `git rebase -s recursive -X ours origin/dev` but git stopped on a conflict. Why is that?

Comment: Apparently, git automatically resolve conflicts only when the same file is modified in both branches. It does not resolve file deletions automatically

Comment: `ours`: the `target-branch`, `theirs`: the `current-branch` :s